# Hiding a button in parent view from its modal view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have a parent view with a hidden button, and a method that unhides that button. That parent view has a modal view in which I need to call the method that hides the button.

**ParentViewController.m**

```
- (void)unhideButton {
    myButton.hidden = NO;
    NSLog(@"Unhide");
}
```

**ModalViewController.m**

```
- (void)levelComplete {
    ParentViewController *controller = [[ParentViewController] alloc] init];
    [controller unhideButton];
    [controller release];
}
```

The NSLog message `Unhide` is successfully showing up in the console, but when I dismiss the modal view controller, the button is still hidden. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you hide the button? That is probably being called again.

Comment: I have it set as hidden in the interface builder.

Answer (score 1):

Modal view controller's have an automatic reference to the view controllers that present using the `parentViewController` property. So you can directly say,

```
[self.parentViewController unhideButton];
```

in the `levelComplete` method.

But yeah creating a new instance and calling the method on it will not affect the original instance like Ryan said.

Comment: this is the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the ModalViewController, which is presumably presented by an instance of ParentViewController, instantiating a *new* ParentViewController? I think what you need to do is pass a reference to the existing ParentViewController to the ModalViewController when you create it, then in ModalViewController it can set the hidden property on the parents button.

If you want to follow good design practices, the ParentViewController needs to delegate the management of its button to the ModalViewController. ParentViewController would conform to a simple protocol, exposing the button, and would set itself as the delegate of the ModalViewController before presenting it.

Comment: Read the [cocoa core competencies guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html), which will take you through the concept of delegation, how it's used in cocoa, and how to implement it in your objects.

Comment: Delegation is one of two main pattern through out cocoa. It is a key to master mac and iphone programming. make sure you really understand it.